# How do I find all the nets of a polyhedron?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, geometry, polyhedra, discrete

The following will show me a single example net of a polyhedron

```
PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Net"]
```

[image]

And

```
PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "NetCount"]
```

tells me that there are 43,380 ways to unfold a dodecahedron.

But I can't find any method that I can use to iterate through all of the nets of a polyhedron to see what they look like. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: The `PolyhedronData` is not well done. For example, `PolyhedronData["Сube", "Net"]` produces "PolyhedronData::notent: Сube is not a known entity, class, or tag for PolyhedronData. Use PolyhedronData[] for a list of entities" though the result of  `PolyhedronData[]` includes `Cube`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of possible nets for complex enough polyhedra is substantially large to overload your resources if algorithm is not smartly designed. You can look at the Source Notebook of the cool function [RandomPolyhedralNet](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RandomPolyhedralNet/) to try to design something efficient. Though the next best thing to "all of the nets" is walking through randomly generated nets. `RandomPolyhedralNet` can take `SeedRandom`. This allows you to design an app like this:

```
Manipulate[
 SeedRandom[k];
 Graphics[Map[Line,
  ResourceFunction["RandomPolyhedralNet"]
  [Entity["Polyhedron", "JabulaniPolyhedron"]]],
 ImageSize->{300,300}],
{k,1,1000,1,Appearance->"Open"}]
```

[image]

You can also display things in a large batches removing potential duplicates - note in batches you also can control reproducibility with `SeedRandom`:

```
batchN=100;SeedRandom[13];
coor=Union[ParallelTable[
 ResourceFunction["RandomPolyhedralNet"]
 [Entity["Polyhedron", "JabulaniPolyhedron"]],batchN]];
Print["Number of removed duplicates = "<>ToString[Length[coor]-batchN]]
Graphics[Map[Line,#],ImageSize->50]&/@coor
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, `ResourceFunction["RandomPolyhedralNet"]["Dodecahedron"]` fails. The documentation says that the command works only with simple polyhedrons.

Comment: @user64494 It does work. If you would look carefully through the docs you'd realize you need to put Entity not String: `ResourceFunction["RandomPolyhedralNet"][
 Entity["Polyhedron", "Dodecahedron"]]`

Comment: @VitalyKaurov: Thank you for your valuable comment.

Comment: When you say "remove duplicates", does it remove duplicates according to isomorphism (i.e. two isomorphic nets are considered duplicates) or is it possible that it will show multiples of the same net that are just rotated differently?

Comment: @PeterOlson not rotated. Just simply duplicates identical in net polygon coordinates.

Comment: @PeterOlson you can try to use `FindGeometricTransform` to detect duplicates via 
basic trnasofrmations.